# Ubuntu showing sched_error 20[ ] on boot

Tags: kubuntu

I am seeing the below message during boot, preventing my system from running:

```
** 19 printk messages dropped **
[200.119021] nouveau <missing> fifo: sched_error 20[<missing>]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I've tried to edit this question to what I *think* the error should say, but I may be wrong. Please [edit] the question yourself to include the *exact* error you're getting such that we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Upon boot, add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the command-line arguments. Do this like so:

1. When booting your computer, hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to get a GRUB menu.
2. Navigate to the `Ubuntu` option and hit <kbd>F3</kbd>.
3. Move your cursor to the `linux` line, after `quiet splash`.
4. Type in `nouveau.modeset=0`, and then hit <kbd>F10</kbd>.

When you've booted into your computer, you're going to have to either [install the NVIDIA drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) or update your boot config to not allow this error to happen further:

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type in the following command, exactly as it appears below:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. You will be prompted with something that looks like `[sudo] password for user:`. Type in your password. You will not see any characters, but rest assured that your password is being typed. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when done.
4. Go to this line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   Edit it to look like:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, followed by the <kbd>Y</kbd> key, followed by the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to save your changes.
6. Run the exact command below to update your bootloader config:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
7. Reboot to confirm that everything is working properly.

Comment: Thanks bro but i resolved the issue it was showing that error because nividia driver package was not installed .

Comment: I am experiencing the same error but it is not showing on boot, it shows when I come back from sleep although I have installed the NVIDIA drivers. When I opened the grub file it had nouveau.runmp=0 replacing this with the one mentioned in the answer solved my problem

Comment: Wish I could up-vote the accepted answer a gazillion times. Fixed the issue for me. I'm running a Clevo P640RE. I also added this to my kernel params: `acpi_osi='!Windows 2015'` - this stopped the random freezing/lock-ups on my laptop.

Answer (score -1):

I use Lenovo Ideapad. I solved this issue via BIOS changes:

- During startup, press F2 key multiple times to enter BIOS.
- In BIOS -> `Configuration` tab -> `Graphic Device` -> `UMA Only`.
- Press F10 to exit savings changes.

Comment: Why is that?? This is not the solution! The "UMA only" option completely disables the high-performance graphics card. In this case, the device only works with Intel graphics card. So, if we are going to disable the high-performance graphics card, why do we pay for a computer? There must be another solution but this is not a solution.

Comment: I answered the the problem to resolve the displayed error, and I'm using the same solution today as well - works perfectly fine. Sometimes, Ubuntu has issues with third-party device drivers and works well when disabled them. If the need is to use high-performance graphics card, then the appropriate driver installation process has to be followed.