# Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot w/ windows 10 cannot install

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I've tried to install Ubuntu on my new laptop with Windows 10 - I was aiming for a dual boot. On the first run everything seemed fine until it asked me to choose my language. It just stopped for more than 10 minutes loading something:

[image]

I tried to shut it down but it had no effect (it asked me "Do you really want to close all running applications?" but didn't do anything). So I turned it off by force. When I attempted to do it again it surprisingly worked I went through the whole installation process and got into Ubuntu. I downloaded a few programs I needed, checked my emails and shut it down.

When turning on again there was a just black screen with white text running for more than half an hour [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897627/ubuntu-showing-sched-error-20-on-boot):

```
** 19 printk messages dropped **
[200.119021] nouveau <missing> fifo: sched_error 20[<missing>]
```

I shut it down by force again and booted Ubuntu without problems. I logged in and spent a few minutes there then opting for restart and choosing to load windows instead. While being on Windows I also removed the USB stick. Then I restarted it again but it gave no options and booted to windows directly. My Ubuntu disappeared.

I decided to attempt the installation again but it always stops at choosing the language like the first time.

What should I do?

I am using Lenovo IdeaPad 510 15 (80SV00RBCK) with graphics cards (I guess): Intel(R) HD Graphics 620, NVIDIA GeForce 940MX. [This is my BIOS settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcZQw.jpg)

When I made a new USB stick (via Etcher) it gets worse. [This is what the installation looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y43Pu.jpg)

All I can see is the numbers and the `83.*******` number iterates by one about each second. I didn't even get to choosing the system language or anything.

Comment: What brand/model system? And what video card/chip? Did you turn off Windows fast start up and UEFI fast boot? When it tries to parse partitions if Windows fast start up or hibernation is on then it has issues. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions I do prefer to partition in advance. But only one ESP (FAT32)  per device. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Good questions, I updated my post. Fast boot is disabled, Windows fast start up is not in my BIOS settings. I've split my SSD disc before installing it, but Ubuntu didn't even ask me where exactly it should install to.

Comment: Fast start is a Windows setting. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Only Something Else install option lets you create or change partitions. I do prefer to use gparted to create partitions and then use Something Else to choose/change to / (root) and others if desired. https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi  see also: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2361230