# Ubuntu bootup and shutdown error of nouveau

Tags: boot, drivers

I have a i5 7th gen laptop having 8gb ram and 2gb nvdia geforce 920mx graphics .I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 and have a black screen coming up during every bootup and shutdown showing **fifo shed error 20** and also during bootup there is a message showing **failed to claim resource 1** I have just started using linux so consider me as a begineer and try to give me the solution in detailed manner

***Nouveau Error is also seen***

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/947582/edit) your question and add the full error output(s) – as photographs if necessary.

Comment: I solved this issue by making BIOS changes https://askubuntu.com/a/1398117/813567

Answer (score 0):

Install Nvidia drivers by running

```
sudo apt install nvidia-375
```

If you are using UEFI, disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: and how do iknow if i am using UEFI and also tell me how to disable secure boot in BIOS

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/167850 This describes how to disable Secure Boot. It is preferrable not to use `mokutil`.