# I had error 'nouveau SCHED_ERROR 20 []' while booting usb live stick on my laptop

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb

I have a laptop with win10. I created a bootable xubuntu usb. I chose the usb from the boot menu and tried xubuntu instead of install. But I had a `nouveau SCHED_ERROR [] 20` error
How can I fix this? If I wait till its charge is over, can I boot win10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/897627/267752 or https://askubuntu.com/q/897627/267752

Comment: What do you mean with 'wait till its charge is over'? If I understood you correctly, then windows 10 should appear again if you unplug the usb and reboot your computer.

Comment: I hit the power button and unpluged the usb but laptop didn't turned off and It continued printing same message.But its charge's over so it turned off and I can reboot my laptop.It means problem solved.