# printk message dropped

Tags: 16.04, boot, kernel

I have installed Ubuntu desktop 16.04.3 the problem is in the booting process i receive a lot of weird messages that starts with "printk message dropped". Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/897627/ubuntu-showing-sched-error-20-on-boot