# How to sovle fifo: SCHED_ERROR 20 [] error when installing ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

My main OS is Windows10 and I want to setup Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS as second from USB flash drive. After choosing flash drive as boot device I have this:

[image]

Comment: Either select to install 3rd party drivers, etc. or don't and boot with `nomodeset`and then install the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: If you are using Lenovo Ideapad, then this should help. It worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1398117/813567